# How to avoid duplicate each loop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each

I had a function that looks like this

```
function show_services_title(show_services){
    $('.service').fadeOut();
    $.each($('.service'), function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500*i).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Now, this functions is invoked when I click on a link, the problem is that when I click the link the function start to show each div with the class 'service', but when I click the link again and the divs haven't finish showing yet then occur a mess in the screen.

Here is an example that simulate the behavior I'm trying to describe and I want to avoid.

http://jsfiddle.net/bw7jn/4/

Comment: How do you want to solve it? Reset the animation when clicked the second time? Or don't start a new one?

Comment: Might `$('.service').stop().fadeOut();` do the trick?

Comment: The ideal will we to don't start a new one, but It really don't matter if the current animation is reseter or the new one is canceled

Comment: PhistucK, let me try that

Comment: As the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) say, don't use `.delay()` for anything where you need any control over the timer. Use `setTimeout()` instead and cancel the timer when the link is clicked again.

Comment: Great! this solve my problem $('.service').stop().fadeOut();

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bw7jn/6/ here is the example, the only issue is that there is a lightly interruption in the animation, but is enough for what I need, thanks!

Comment: It's still messed up if you click on the link rapidly multiple times. Or even double-click it.

Comment: @Juhana thanks, I will take that in consideration

Comment: Let me try to set a timeout instead of delay, and see what results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable running the animation the second time when the previous animation is still running.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link').click(function(){
        show_services_title();
    });
});

function show_services_title(show_services){

    //if we're already animating, don't start a new one
    if($('ul').attr('data-animating') != 'true'){

        //make sure other clicks dont trigger this animation
        $('ul').attr('data-animating', 'true');
        $('.service').fadeOut();
        $.each($('.service'), function(i, element) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(element).fadeIn();

                //check if this is the last element we're gonna animate
                if(i == $('.service').length-1){
                    //animation is done, allow new animations to start
                    $('ul').attr('data-animating', 'false');   
                }
            }, 500*i);
        });
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bw7jn/7/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the `if(i == $('.service').length - 1) {...}` is placed in a callback, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bw7jn/8/)?